# error querying data with apostrophes

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, sql-injection

I'm getting empty sets from running the following query permutations:

```
select * 
from gsapi_articles 
where article_title = "James Dean On Merilyn: 'This Woman Is A True Marvel'"

select * 
from gsapi_articles 
where article_title = "James Dean On Merilyn: \'This Woman Is A True Marvel\'"
```

Not sure whats wrong.

Comment: -1 for presenting political views here, which is way off topic.  Also, you could easily find the answer in the MySQL documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you write your query in SQL you must doubled your ' in this way:

```
select * from gsapi_articles
where article_title = 'James Woods On Obama: ''This President Is A True Abomination'''
```

Comment: You can escape a single quote with `\'` in MySQL. You don't have to use `''`